# Remove single backSlash from String

Tags: ios, swift, string

i try send json parameter to server. there is all my code but i have an problem in backslash character. 
this is test variable result that contain backSlash character. i should remove this character because in server side i got an invalid input error and server can't detect send parameter.

test variable after replacing character"
"{\"force\":\"1\",\"from\":\"0\",\"flag\":\"1\",\"to\":\"0\",\"spec\":{\"propValueMask\":\"*\",\"itemsType\":\"avl_resource\",\"sortType\":\"sys_name\",\"propType\":\"avl_resource\",\"propName\":\"sys_name\"}}"

```
private func RegisterForGetSourceList() {

    var sid = ""

    if let authEntity = AuthenticationManager.shareInstance.fetchAuthenticationEntity() {

        if let tokenKey = authEntity.sID {
            sid = tokenKey
        }
    }

    let specParam = [
        "itemsType": "avl_resource",
        "propName": "sys_name",
        "propValueMask": "*",
        "sortType": "sys_name",
        "propType": "avl_resource"
    ]

    let paramJSON: [String: Any] = [
        "spec": specParam,
        "force": "1",
        "flag": "1",
        "from": "0",
        "to": "0"
        ]

    do {

        let paramData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramJSON, options: .prettyPrinted)

        if let paramString = NSString(data: paramData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {

            var test = String(paramString.characters.filter { !" \n\t\r".characters.contains($0) })

            test = test.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)

            let parameters = [Constant.SVC:Constant.SEARCH_ITEMS_SVC,Constant.SID:sid,Constant.PARAM:test] as [String: Any]

            LibraryAPI.shareInstance.RunHttpPostJSONRequest(parameters: parameters, contentType: "JSON", closure: { success, error in

                if let result = success as? [String: Any] {
                    if let eid = result["eid"] as? String {}
                } else if error != nil  {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "there was an error in get response")
                }
            })
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

i read many link, in All of theme were suggested replacing "\" but that is not working. 
Someone has some suggestions to solve this problem
 Thanks.

Comment: The backslashes are virtual. They are necessary to display double quotes in a literal string. They are **not** sent to the server.

Comment: ... and it's nonsense to *pretty print* the string and later remove the spaces and line separators. The server does not care at all about esthetics. Delete the option.

Answer (score 2):

As vadian has suggested, the string backslashes are virtual and not sent to the server.

If you want to print the json for debugging, I recommend this approach:

```
var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: paramData, options: .allowFragments)
```

Make sure this is wrapped inside your do-catch block.

If you want the json as a string, you can do:

```
let convertedString = String(data: paramData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: Yes, and anyway OP should convert the JSON *data* to objects, without using the string representation at all except for debugging. This is a common mistake. The JSON string is not needed for doing the conversions.